# SAP HANA Calculated Column Exception Handling

Tags: exception, calculated-columns, hana

In SAP HANA you can create a calculated column. One example of a calculated column is converting string to integer.

Unfortunately in the source column are not always numbers (we expected only numbers)

So is there a way to do exception Handing for calculated columns (or any other kind of a default value in case of failure?

Answer (score 0):

Workaround:

Check if the cell is numeric. And use a fall-back value if the cell is not numeric:

```
case 
 when length(ltrim(WERT_TEXT,' +-.0123456789')) > 0 then 0
  else trim("WERT_TEXT")
end
```